# Passing Values from PopUp Window

Tags: javascript, php, popup

I have created a file manager popup window which currently am only using to upload files. Now I want to configure it so that it can be called from a form and after selecting files pass the file names to the parent window.

Is it possible to do that? If so, how can I pass values from popup windows to it's opener?

Comment: When you say popup: it's `alert` or `prompt` or `comfirm`, or it is a custom dialogue box?

Comment: nah a window created from javascript with restrictions

Comment: If file upload is in html form , then you see its all values in $_POST php variable

Comment: nah what i want to do is to pass file names from file manager window to the window which the file manager originated from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried the [Window opener Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp) ?

Maybe can you post some code in order to have a better comprehension of what you want ?

Comment: sry found the solution it seems you can control the value of the parent window from the popup like this

self.parent.opener.document.form.field.value = 'new value'

Comment: Good, it is the answer that I posted too. Maybe you could accept it, it would be great :-)